# How do I resize the partition in which Ubuntu is installed?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu in a 50 GB partition. I felt so good with the system that I decided to use it as the main OS so I erased the other OS. I deleted everything in Windows partition. Now, how do I add those 110 GB to the Ubuntu's partition.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1, downloaded from the official website on a HP system.

Comment: Yo soy nuevo, no se ingles ahora es que estoy usando este foro y preguntando dudas no tengo la intencion de copiar ni nada

Comment: @MiguelAngelMateo No es una copia, le dirige a una pregunta anterior que fue bien respondida.

Comment: No te preocupes, @MiguelAngelMateo . El hecho que tomaste el tiempo a traducirlo ya te pone por encima de la gran majoria de usuarios nuevos. Muchísimas gracias por el esfuerzo!

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use live USB and Gparted program following way:

1. You boot the live USB or CD
2. Launch Gparted
3. Using Gparted you extend and move your partition in a desired way.
4. After applying changes you quit Gparted and reboot your new system (be sure remove live USB).

Comment: As? Do I download the Ubuntu installation file and boot it to the USB and install it again?

Comment: You make a live USB using downloaded Ubuntu iso and a program called Unetbootin. When booting live USB, choose try Ubuntu in the menu, this will lead you to a live session, then just start Gparted from the menu.